# unable to set localstorage with product as the state initially changes

Tags: reactjs, mern

i am working on eCommerce project , i am currently facing a problem where as user clicks on add to cart button the code  **setCart([...cart,item])** runs since the initial state of cart is empty array like **const [cart,setCart] = useState([])** therefore as i try to save it on **localstorage** it gives me empty array and then start saving data in second array

code:

```
  const [cartValue,setCartValue] = useState(0)
   
  const [cart,setCart] = useState([])


  const cartValueIncreaserandSetter = (item) =>{

    setCart([...cart,item])
  setCartValue(cartValue+1)
localStorage.setItem("items",JSON.stringify(cart))

  }
```

i want the localstorage to immediately save the first item added but the localstorage gives **[]** array on first click on add to cart

Comment: setCard is not executed instantly, so your card will still be empty when doing your call to localStorage, just put ([cart, ...item]) in your call to localStorage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have side effect in your code (which is the case when you manipulate the localstorage) you should use the `useEffect` hook.

I suggest you to rewrite your code like this :

```
const [cartValue,setCartValue] = useState(0)
const [cart,setCart] = useState([])

const cartValueIncreaserandSetter = (item) => {
  setCart([...cart, item])
  setCartValue(cartValue+1)
}

useEffect(() => {
  localStorage.setItem("items",JSON.stringify(cart))
}, [cart]);
```

Answer (score 1):

That happens because the `useState` hook is asynchronous.

try using the existing cart and append the item (which came as a parameter) like this:

```
localStorage.setItem("items",JSON.stringify([...cart,item]))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (cart.length > 0) localStorage.setItem("items", JSON.stringify(cart));
}, [cart]);
```